# React Js Proxy error: Could not proxy request only on Chrome works fine in Firefox

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, proxy, lerna

I am using React + Learna to bundle multiple packages for different feature and assigned different ports to them

Now the issue I am facing when I try to load react application using localhost:3000 In terminal I am getting an error

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /static/js/bundle.js from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3002.
```

This error only occurs in chrome, it works fine in firefox. Btw I need to use vpn to hit login apis and those apis also give me 401-unauthorized error still i am with vpn (works fine in Firefox).

Now I don't know whether issue is with chrome browser proxy? as I have tried to add localhost to ignore in proxy setting but no luck.
Also I tried to add secure: false in package.json but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
Go to chrome://flags

Search following flag and disable it

1. SameSite by default cookies
2. Cookies without SameSite must be secure

Close the browser and reopen it. It should work fine